# How could someone alter the composition of air sufficiently so that plant life gets more nutrients and grows faster

Tags: science-based, flora, terrorism

Im writing a story about a group of eco-terrorists who are trying to make the flora of a planet take over major cities and create a utopian wasteland. They have access to a macguffin that can alter the molecular composition of different gases, which they want to use to make the air better for plants so that the grow faster, aided by different things. How exactly could they do this?

Comment: Please note that "alter the molecular composition of different gases" means changing gases.

Comment: Any possible changes in air composition can have only minor positive effect on plant growth. You'll need years to see the difference. On the other hand, stronger climate changes would be inevitable if we are to increase CO2 concentration, for example, and those changes would be a much stronger factor affecting plant life.

Comment: Do you really mean a Utopian wasteland, or do you mean a dystopian wasteland? I don't understand. Maybe a Utopian gardenscape?

Comment: "Utopian wasteland" is an contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Mathaddict Actually, that was a clever use of the words to create an oxymoron. I love the idea of ecoterrorists seeking to create a "utopian wasteland" - a place where Man is overcome to create a perfect place for nature. Nice idea, Shrike!

Comment: They don't even need a macguffin, all they need is fossil fuels. 

Chlorophyll in modern plants evolved in a time when the atmospheric concentration of CO2 was much higher. Just by putting more CO2 in the air, your plants are going to grow faster. 

Ironic then, that your eco terrorists must do exactly what humanity has been doing all along: burning fossil fuels to add CO2 to the atmosphere, just at a much, much higher rate. Add on top of that a bioengineered plant virus to up the metabolism of plants, and they will grow out of control quite easily.

Comment: @stix Plants don't do well with rapid climate change.  Any benefit you'd get from CO2 would be undone by plants withering and dying from the heat; so, you'd need to also work in some more reflective upper atmospheric gasses like O3 to mitigate the warming effect.

Answer (score 3):

Tweak the humidity and increase the CO2:

- [1300ppm CO2](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/00-077.htm) This isn't a dangerous level.
- [45-55% humidity (NSFW - marijuana growth)](https://420intel.com/articles/2018/05/30/what%E2%80%99s-best-grow-room-temperature-and-humidity-level).

Oxygen is the only other gas that directly affects a plant, which can stay where it is. They can't absorb nitrogen from the air because of the N3 triple bond.

Plants get everything else from the roots, but your macguffen can have those things in the air in tiny quantities so they settle into the soil next time it rains.

> the macronutrients: nitrogen (N), phosphorus (P), potassium (K), calcium (Ca), sulfur (S), magnesium (Mg), carbon (C), oxygen (O), hydrogen (H)
> the micronutrients (or trace minerals): iron (Fe), boron (B), chlorine (Cl), manganese (Mn), zinc (Zn), copper (Cu), molybdenum (Mo), nickel (Ni)

From [Plant Nutrition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_nutrition) on Wikipedia.

**But wait, there's more...**

Your macguffen can also put trace amounts of silver iodide in the atmosphere. While not required by plants, they [can introduce rainfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding), the ability to create rain when needed will help with plant growth, and the ability to remove overcast clouds and let the sun through will also help with growth.

Comment: 1200 PPM of CO2 certainly IS dangerous.  Probably fatal to most higher life forms, due to increased temperatures & knock-on effects.  Likewise more rain or whatever does not generally help with plant growth.  Plants evolve to grow in a certain range of conditions.  Too much rain will kill desert plants as surely as too little will kill plants adapted to wet conditions.

Comment: @jamesqf: The question asks only about plants. Plants are fine at 1200 ppm CO2. (Yes, the climate would change, and this of course would imply a massive redistribution of humans, with the inevitable wars etc. But the question is about plants.)

Comment: @jamesqf You're allowed to work for 8 hours at 5000ppm -     https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/wcm/connect/bf97edac-77be-4442-aea4-9d2615f376e0/Carbon-Dioxide.pdf?MOD=AJPERES -

Comment: Silver iodide is an amazing idea! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Operation Stormfury is a really interesting story about how the US Government wanted to use it.

Comment: @AlexP: But as I said, raising the atmospheric CO2 concentration to that level would render the Earth unhabitable to most higher life forms.  The point is that it doesn't STAY at that level: it's beyond the tipping point where things like methane clathrates start decomposing, so you get a Permian-Triassic like event.

Answer (score 2):

**Using the atmosphere? Probably not. But you can use the technology of Humanity against them...**

I sell the coolest product: *Exceed Superior [Legume Inoculant](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/beans/soil-inoculants.htm).* It's a bacteria in the form of a powder spread on plants (beans, peas, etc. in this case) after they've germinated and what it does is help the plant draw more nutrients from the soil faster and more efficiently. The result is the plant's product is substantially increased.

Now, you're looking for something a bit monstrous — but rather than looking for a scientifically verified way of converting the Earth to a utopian wasteland (I really do love that phrase), let's shoot for *suspension of disbelief.*

Our traditional mad scientist starts with the technology behind legume inoculants and creates a version that allows any plant to just run wild with growth. The plants will still need sunlight and water — in fact, they'll need lots of both (increased growth demands increased resources), so the plants will run wild in sunny, well-watered areas but will have trouble in cloudy or poor soil locations.  But that's not relevant, right?

Because what we have is a powder that can be spread by airplane that can "believably" solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Tabun

By filling the air with [Tabun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabun_(nerve_agent)) you can kill off most mammals while leaving plant life and pollin spreading insects mostly unaffected.  With mammals all suddenly dead, the bodies will begin to decompose leaving behind tons of fertile soil for plants.  Furthermore, with so many of the world's herbivores (and let's face it, Humans) killed off, plant life will quickly over take places that it could not establish itself before.

Comment: This would be bad news for plants that depend on mammals for spreading seeds and pollination.